# Python module telethon error (Error caused by GetChannelDifferenceRequest)

Tags: python, python-3.x, telethon

i have this error

Telegram is having internal issues HistoryGetFailedError: Fetching of history failed (caused by GetChannelDifferenceRequest)

can you guys help me ?

```
async def my_event_handler(event):
    global lire, t
    lire = event.raw_text
    print(lire)
    while True:
        while t >= 0:
            print(text[t])
            try:
                await client.send_message(text[t], lire)
                t-=1
            except Exception as exception:
                t-=1
            await asyncio.sleep(0.3)
        t = len(text) - 1
        await asyncio.sleep(30)
```

Comment: Telegram is having internal issues. You cannot fix this. You can only wait for Telegram to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please describe the kind of help that you are requesting.

Comment: How can i resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Kinda late to the party here.

You can actually import the exception for HistoryGetFailedError from the Telethon errors class.

You need to add what could be seen as redundancy logic or "retry" logic.

Create another exception to handle the HistoryGetFailedError, and within that exception create a loop that loosely resembles this:

```
for i in range(0,30):
    print(f"Sleeping 1 sec for Retry HistoryGetFailedError Iteration {i}"
    try:
        client.send_message(text[t], lire)
    except HistoryGetFailedError as hsgfe:
        continue
    break
```

The point of this being within the original exception is as  @Lonami said in your comments section you simply must wait for Telegram to catch up on their end. This gives you a 30 sec +- windows of retry. Usually these requests clear up after 5-10 seconds from my experience, but if not handled they can paint your logs red and kill the service of whatever you are running. Hope this helped to some capacity Cheers!

NOTE: My code is not meant for production use here, it is pseudo code, I am not familiar with Async functions, so I did not want to build an actual representation of the solution, however I am experienced with Telethon and Python

Comment: Also Feel free to DM me with anything Telegram/Telethon related. I am happy to offer any help where I can cheers.